# C# Reactive Extensions - Subscribe to stream of aggregation

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I Have a stream of points and would like to combine each 2 points in order to draw a line .

```
public class MyPoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

I am looking for something that would combine the functionality of Aggregate and Select , Meaning that i would like to later Subscribe to ether a complex type combining the 2 points , or to receive an aggregation as a parameter to my Observer's OnNext delegate :

Something like :

```
    pointObservable.Subscribe((prev, curr) => { });
```

or

```
    pointObservable.Subscribe((myLineStruct) => { });
```

Sample to build on :

```
  List<MyPoint> points = new List<MyPoint>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
       points.Add(new MyPoint{ X = i , Y = i * 10});
  }

  IObservable<MyPoint> pointObservable = points.ToObservable();
```

After trying 2 solutions , i came across some issues :

First of here is my actual Stream :

```
observable  // Stream of 250 points arriving every interval 
     .Take(_xmax + 10)   // for test purposes take only the Graph + 10 
     .Select(NormalizeSampleByX) // Nomalize X  ( override Real X with display X (
     .Scan(new PlotterEcgSample(-1, 0), MergeSamplesWithDistinctX)  // which returns current only if current.X > prev.X 
     .DistinctUntilChanged() // remove all redundant previous points elements 

     // here i end up with a stream of normalized points 

     .Zip(observable.Skip(1), (prev, curr) => new {Prev = prev, Curr = curr})
             // Dmitry Ledentsov 's addition  
            .Subscribe(res =>
            {
               Debug.WriteLine(" {0} {1}  , {2} {3}", res.Prev.X, res.Prev.Y, res.Curr.X , res.Curr.Y);   
            });
```

with Dmitry's addition i get the following result .

```
0 862  , 252 -21 
1 888  , 253 -24 
2 908  , 254 -28 
3 931  , 255 -31 
4 941  , 256 -35 
5 890  , 257 -38 
6 802  , 258 -41 
7 676  , 259 -44 
8 491  , 260 -48 
9 289  , 261 -51 
10 231  , 262 -55
```

@Enigmativity's suggestion :

```
 observable.Take(_xmax + 10)
            .Select(NormalizeSample)
            .Scan(new PlotterEcgSample(-1, 0), MergeSamplesWithDistinctX)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Publish(obs => obs.Zip(observable.Skip(1), (prev, curr) => new {Prev = prev, Curr = curr}))
            .Subscribe(res =>
            {
               Debug.WriteLine(" {0} {1}  , {2} {3}", res.Prev.X, res.Prev.Y, res.Curr.X , res.Curr.Y);   
            });
```

results in :

```
 59 862  , 1 -21 
 60 867  , 2 -24 
 61 893  , 3 -28 
 62 912  , 4 -31 
 63 937  , 5 -35 
 64 937  , 6 -38 
 65 870  , 7 -41 
 66 777  , 8 -44 
 67 632  , 9 -48 
 68 444  , 10 -51 
 69 289  , 11 -55  
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observable.Scan` is the easiest way to fold or compare current and previous items. I blogged on this [here with some nice diagrams](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=213). Here is the code from that article, with an example specifically with points. The extension method is very flexible though, and it works with any source and result types:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> CombineWithPrevious<TSource,TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return source.Scan(
        Tuple.Create(default(TSource), default(TSource)),
        (previous, current) => Tuple.Create(previous.Item2, current))
        .Select(t => resultSelector(t.Item1, t.Item2));
}
```

So if you have a complex type Delta like this:

```
public class Delta
{
    public Point P1 { get;set; }
    public Point P2 { get;set; }

    public static Delta Create(Point P1, Point P2)
    {
        return new Delta {
            P1 = P1,
            P2 = P2
        };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Delta is (" + (P2.X - P1.X)
            + "," + (P2.Y - P1.Y) + ")");
    }
}
```

You can use as follows:

```
Subject<Point> ps = new Subject<Point>();

ps.CombineWithPrevious(Delta.Create)
  .Subscribe(d => Console.WriteLine(d));

ps.OnNext(new Point(1,1));
ps.OnNext(new Point(2,2));
ps.OnNext(new Point(2,3));
```

Your output will be:

```
Delta is (0,0)
Delta is (1,1)
Delta is (1,1)
Delta is (2,3)
```

Note that `default(TSource)` is used to set an initial default - you can easily modify this to specify an initial default value, or handle that in the result selector, or skip the first element etc (`.Skip(1)`) - there are lots of options.

Comment: You've answered the same question earlier. You could have voted this question to close(which I did). But +1 for the nice diagrams :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I thought a  while about it, but decided to modify to work with points and talk about the resultSelector and defaults. I thought the question here was a little more discoverable. It was a close call.

Comment: Works great , thanks . i just added a Skip(1) after the scan to avoid the first null item, i want to start at ( 0 , Y ) - (1 , Y any ways , thanks .

I'm sure the other guys gave great working answers as well but i just didn't wan't to complicate things with my complicated stream , when now i see it was probably unavoidable since the Zip answer gives me wierd an unexpected results .

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably zipping the sequence with a shifted original sequence:

```
var res = pointObservable.Zip(
    pointObservable.Skip(1),
    (p1, p2) => new { A = p1, B = p2 }
);

res.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

resulting in

```
{ A = (0,0), B = (1,10) }
{ A = (1,10), B = (2,20) }
{ A = (2,20), B = (3,30) }
{ A = (3,30), B = (4,40) }
{ A = (4,40), B = (5,50) }
{ A = (5,50), B = (6,60) }
{ A = (6,60), B = (7,70) }
{ A = (7,70), B = (8,80) }
{ A = (8,80), B = (9,90) }
```

given a `ToString` Method for `MyPoint`

Update:

as of the comments, in order to avoid unwanted side effects on subscriptions, the original sequence has to be `Publish`ed before zipping. Thus, [James World's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28873998/847349) using `Scan` is probably what you should use.

Using James' `CombineWithPrevious`:

```
var res = pointObservable
    .CombineWithPrevious((p1, p2) => new { A = p1, B = p2 })
    .Skip(1);
```

gives the same result

or a more succint version by Engimativity:

```
var res = pointObservable
    .Publish(po => 
        po.Zip(
            po.Skip(1),
            (p1, p2) => new { A = p1, B = p2 }
        )
    );
```

Comment: A pretty good solution, but it's a good idea to `.Publish` the `pointObservable` before doing the zip to avoid any possible side-effects (i.e. caused by double subscriptions).

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks! Indeed, it might be a good idea. To make it work properly, one would have to know the context it is going to be used. If the sequence is not timed, like in the minimal console example, the subscription would miss all the values

Comment: Note that one of the key advantages of the `Scan` approach is that no publishing is required.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov - You don't need to do a full `.Publish` with `.Connect`. You can do it like this: `var res = pointObservable.Publish(po => po.Zip(po.Skip(1), (p1, p2) => new { A = p1, B = p2 }));`. All inline and it returns an `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: This actually didn't work like i excepted  see the edit to my question

Comment: @Enigmativity that one is interesting too, and succint

Comment: @eranotzap - Of course it didn't work - you used two different observables, one had a bunch of operators after your `observable`, but the other one was just `observable.Skip(1)`. They need to be the same observable. Try doing it with my `.Publish` suggestion above. That should make it work.

Comment: @Enigmativity i'm trying to understand what you suggested , i can't seem to get it to work . 

Could we speak here ? : 

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: @eranotzap - After `.DistinctUntilChanged()` put `.Publish(o => o.Zip(o.Skip(1), (prev, curr) => new {Prev = prev, Curr = curr}))`.

Comment: it seems like it's combining 2 streams from the results , 
two  nearly 250 streams . i can't seem to understand the results..

Comment: @eranotzap try forking this project to post a full minimal working example: https://github.com/d-led/csharp_travis_example

Comment: sure i'll do it later today

Answer (score 1):

You want `Scan`:

```
points
    .Scan((LineSegment)null, (prev, point) => new LineSegment(prev == null ? point : prev.End, point))
    .Skip(1) // skip the first line segment which will not be valid
    .Subscribe(lineSegment => ... );
```